# Display a dynamic text file content in a web page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am redirecting my cron job result to a text file . So the text file updates every 2 mins . This text file will be in my server .

how can i display the up to date content of the text file in the web page . i am new to this and have no idea how it could be . Please help me in resolving this .

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your codes.

Comment: Because php gets executed, you'll need to keep refreshing the page to get the latest version. Add onto what I marked as a duplicate with a bit of javascript.